# Is there a way to recover objects from a set in the same order as passed?

Tags: java, set, hashset

I need to recover the elements of a java Set collection interface in the same order they were passed into the set.

How is it possible in java

Comment: Why can you not just use a `List`?

Comment: Do you control the implementation or is this someone else's code? LinkedHashSet provides predictable ordering, but if you are just calling into the Set interface and the implementation is something akin to HashSet you're out of luck. Sets by definition are not guaranteed to be ordered.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y the two most obvious reasons I can think of are: the asker doesn't control the interface that is providing the `Set`, or the asker wants to guarantee an element only appears in it once.

Comment: @space_cowboy I want to guarentee the element apopears only once. and also i dont have much control over the code

Answer (score 10):

How about [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) ?

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

Answer (score 4):

```
public class SimpleLinkedHashSetExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create object of LinkedHashSet
    LinkedHashSet lhashSet = new LinkedHashSet();

    /*
      Add an Object to LinkedHashSet using
      boolean add(Object obj) method of Java LinkedHashSet class.
      This method adds an element to LinkedHashSet if it is not 
      already present in LinkedHashSet.
      It returns true if the element was added to LinkedHashSet, false otherwise.
    */

    lhashSet.add(new Integer("1"));
    lhashSet.add(new Integer("2"));
    lhashSet.add(new Integer("3"));

    /*
      Please note that add method accepts Objects. Java Primitive values CAN NOT
      be added directly to LinkedHashSet. It must be converted to corrosponding
      wrapper class first.
    */

    System.out.println("LinkedHashSet contains.." + lhashSet);   
  }
}

/*
Output of the program would be
LinkedHashSet contains..[1, 2, 3]
*/
```

You can use LinkedhashSet above is the example.